# Moodle exausting memory available to PHP

Tags: php, shared-hosting, moodle

This is the error I'm getting using some features of moodle on a shared hosting provider:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 76 bytes) in /home/myusername/public_html/lib/moodlelib.php on line 8071
```

First I thought the php memory limit was set too low, but 64MB seems perfectly acceptable... Is moodle so memory-hungry that it would need more than that?

If that's the case, and considering I'm using a shared hosting and that it's likely unlikely they will increase the memory limit just for me, how can I work around it?

I'm using moodle 2.4.3.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you are stuck in some infinite loop?

Comment: The message appears too often and using very different moodle features, so I think that's not it. The php file and line number aren't always the same.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the line number to always be the same, but I would guess that perhaps these line numbers are all within some common section of code where you are trying to put a large amount of data in memory.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But how can I work around it? :(

Comment: You don't work around it. You need to find out why you are trying to allocate this much memory.  Debug your application.

Comment: It's just happening in too many different situations. I'm not really seeking a way to make moodle more memory efficient on all those cases. And I'm using a stable version of moodle, so I'm pretty sure this is not a bug... and I'd expect it to just work.

Comment: But if you're right, and there's no way to work around it, than I guess I'm stuck :\

Comment: The problem may not be in moodle at all (it probably isn't) it is likely in how you are using it.  I am not really familiar with moodle, by you might be doing things like trying to load an entire database result set into memory at once rather than looping through a result set and working with one record at a time, using a bad plug-in or any number of things.  You should look for common theme in how you are getting these errors.  If you get a line number, see if that line number occurs within a loop.  Try to understand what that loop does.

Comment: @MikeBrant thank you for the suggestions, but I really think that's not the way to go. I don't want to debug moodle. Imagine that I would find all the places where moodle is loading stuff into memory, what could I do then? I imagine I could try to optimize moodle's code. I.e., change it. And submit a patch to moodle's maintainers. That's not the level of involvement I'm looking for. I'm just seeking a solution to make it work with the server resources that I have.

Comment: I'm having the same message and the FAQ for Errors in Moodle is not helping at all. Any work arounds ?

Comment: @Bor Sorry, no. I ended up having to upgrade to a server with higher PHP memory limits :\

Answer (score 1):

Moodle provides a function to raise memory limit.
If you do not have access to the php.ini file, you can configure Moodle to do so.

Edit the `config.php` file within the moodle root directory.
Add 
`raise_memory_limit(MEMORY_STANDARD);` or 
`raise_memory_limit(MEMORY_EXTRA);` to the end of that file (somewhere behind `require_once([...]setup.php');`).

Answer (score 0):

> 64MB seems perfectly acceptable... Is moodle so memory-hungry that it
>   would need more than that?

In short: yes!

We used to have the same problem.  Our `php.ini`'s `memory_limit` setting has been set to `256M` for quite some time.  (We're currently using Moodle 2.6, but we saw this problem with 2.1 or 2.2 if memory serves.)

Memory use will vary with Moodle use, of course, but we kept on increasing the setting by 32Mb until the problem went away. (We do run our own servers so adding physical memory is a no-brainer.)